# How to create an element and set unnamed parameters

Tags: javascript, html

I'm used to creating html-elements in JavaScript like so:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('id', 'some_id');
div.setAttribute('custom_attribute', 'some_other_value');
```

But what if my `div` should look like:

```
<div class="uk-grid" data-uk-sortable data-uk-grid-margin>
```

Please, pay attention to these two parameters (or should I call it another way?) - `data-uk-sortable` and `data-uk-grid-margin`. How can I create them programmatically? PS. I'm not even sure, whether I should call these parameters "unnamed". Probably, there is a better convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following

```
<div class="uk-grid" data-uk-sortable data-uk-grid-margin>
```

Is the same as

```
<div class="uk-grid" data-uk-sortable="" data-uk-grid-margin="">
```

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('id', 'some_id');
div.setAttribute('data-uk-sortable', '');
div.setAttribute('data-uk-grid-margin', '');



// just for the demo
document.write(div.outerHTML.replace(/</, '&lt;'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
div.setAttribute('data-uk-grid-margin', '');
```

Comment: That does create an attribute looking like `<div data-uk-grid-margin=""></div>`, but it shouldn't matter.